# Performance difference between using the Doctrine QueryBuilder and findBy()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I recently noticed that one of our cronjob commands was running out of memory and investigated to reduce memory usage. The culprit was an SQL query fetching all articles. I first checked what changed lately that may have been sub-optimal and noticed that a longer time ago it got rewritten with the QueryBuilder instead of a `findBy()` initially, together with more conditions.
I was curious and wanted to see how the additional conditions affected the query (mainly performance, whether it got worse; it was also very slow) and IIRC it didn't have much of an effect. So I also compared the `findBy()` via the QueryBuilder way, with the same conditions.

Some details beforehand:
Symfony 4.4 LTS, Doctrine 2.7 (doctrine/orm) & PHP 7.4
512 MiB memory limit
(ran a variation of the command, with a smaller dataset, not the failing one ofc)

Results:

```
$articles = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->where('a.type = :type')
    ->setParameter('type', $this->appType)
    ->andWhere('a.movedTo is null')
    ->andWhere('a.redirectedTo IS NULL')
    ->orderBy('a.ausyUpdatedAt', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

QueryBuilder: ~70 s execution time, 238 MiB peak memory usage

```
$articles = $this->findBy(['type' => $this->appType, 'movedTo' => null, 'redirectedTo' => null], ['ausyUpdatedAt' => 'DESC']);
```

findBy: ~36 s, 197 MiB

How comes they result in such a different performance? Shouldn't they be the same? What is happening differently, how could one get the QueryBuilder way to the same level? We are using the QueryBuilder in pretty much the whole application, so it would be interesting to know.

In the end, I solved the problem by using `getArrayResult()` to not do the object hydration as we don't need the entities in that case anyways. This improved performance further (5x as fast over the QueryBuilder code seen here) and reduced memory usage quite a bit (peak of 101 MiB for this now).

Comment: I'm a little bit skeptical of your results but it can be hard to pin down specific numbers.  I'd suggest taking a look at the generated SQL queries.  They should be basically identical.  In any event, if arrays are all you need then grab the DBAL connection object and write your query directly in SQL.  That eliminates quite a few layers of ORM code and should give you optimum results.

Comment: I'll check the queries and will try to double-check the results - the testing has been done two weeks ago. Should also note that the application is running in a Docker container and I have XDebug set up and it was probably enabled, which slows down performance generally. I know that executing raw SQL will give the best performance results, but I wanted to do less changes and it's still nice to have  the columns transformed, like `datetime`. As it runs in a cronjob, execution time isn't so much a problem.

Comment: Ok, so after first getting the logging to work, I think I found the reason: for findBy() I got the one expected select query, but for the QueryBuilder way I couldn't even see it because of thousands of other queries being logged; for each article another query was issued to resolve some relation. I waited at least a minute for all log messages to be displayed.^^ Checking the `findBy()` code I see it uses the `HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT` mode when there are no joins, which is "optimized for performance" - I assume `getResult()` uses the normal `HYDRATE_OBJECT` mode.

Comment: Considered adding a limit to the query so that every row isn't returned and iterating over the remaining data in batches?

Comment: @Tez Sure, batching is always a possibility when working with a lot of data, but it's not yet needed in this case. It currently takes less than half of the memory available peak and finishes in about 2s on production (no XDebug). Also, the cronjobs are running in a separate container ofc and don't affect the web application. This question was not about improving performance for the command (wouldn't have been enough info anyways) but specifically about the curious performance difference between those two ways.

Comment: Not sure if I should answer it myself, as I found out the reason for that as I wrote..